# C# : using Regex to match 4 numbers in a long line of text

Tags: c#, regex

Below is a text file not code,

```
Register: 0x0090 = 0x009D  //blah blah blah blah
Register: 0x0091 = 0x03F6 //blah blah blah blah
Register: 0x0092 = 0x0048  //blah blah blah blah
Register: 0x0093 = 0x00C8  //blah blah blah blah
```

I need to extract the register contents, excluding the "0x".I've been going crazy trying to solve this, I have come up with two solutions, both are close to working I guess. I've been using Regex as its what I've learned so far, if you explain another method please give a good explanation.

To get the line I want, I am using StreamReader, assuming I want the third line I would do it like this,

```
stringLine1 = stringLine1 + objReader.ReadLine() + "\r\n";
stringLine2 = stringLine2 + objReader.ReadLine() + "\r\n";
stringLine3 = stringLine3 + objReader.ReadLine() + "\r\n";
```

Using Regex, solution 1:

```
stringLine3 = Regex.Match(stringLine3, @"[^Register: 0x0092 = 0x][0-9A-Z]+").Value;
```

Problem with this method, is if register has content 0028,-it doesn't read the 2!

Solution 2:

```
stringLine3 = Regex.Match(stringLine3, @"(?<=x)\d{4}").Value;
```

So this is a positive lookbehind which grabs 4 numbers proceeded by an 'x', The problem ofcourse is that it is grabbing the register number instead of the contents....

Any suggestions on how to fix this or do it better?

Comment: Hi there, add the language you are using as regex flavor, so you get specific help. It Seems C# but I'm not sure.

Comment: first time posting, not sure how to do that! yeah it is C sharp. should I just put it in title?

Comment: Someone already did it for you :)

Comment: FYI Your first regex has a **character class** = a set of characters inside brackets, or, as in your case, a negated one (the initial `^` inside the brackets), i.e. your `[^Register: 0x0092 = 0x]` matches any character not in the class - any of `Register: 0x92=`. Since `0028` contains a `2` it won't match. Anyways it matches any character not in the class, followed by any number of digits **or** capital ("english") letters. You probably mean it like `^Register: 0x0092 = 0x[0-9A-F]+` which matches a string starting with `Register: 0x0092 = 0x` followed by any number (>=1) of hexadecimal char's.

Comment: That's because it **matches** the whole string. Use the `Match`'s Group method to get group 1=the first **captured** group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a lookbehind :

```
(?<== 0x)[0-9A-F]{4}
```

Or using a group :

```
^Register: 0x[0-9A-F]{4} = 0x([0-9A-F]{4})
```

In this second case, you must retrieve the first group instead of the whole match.

Comment: Thanks for that! I need to research using groups as it seems better practise, Ill use the first method for now

Answer (score 1):

The fist regex you have is wrong. It should be like

```
Register: 0x0092 = 0x([0-9A-Z]+)
```

Here the content of the register is captured in group 1.

- `([0-9A-Z]+)` Matches digits or caps, captures in group 1.

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/xH3lH5/2)

---

**What is wrong in the regex 1?**

- `[^Register: 0x0092 = 0x]` This, `[]` is a character class. Which means that it tries to match anything other than `R` or `e` or `g` or etc. This anything other is becuase you put a `^` which negates the class. If you remove the `^`, it will match anything in the character class.

---

An example code can be written as

```
String stringLine3 = "Register: 0x0092 = 0x0048  //blah blah blah blah";
Match match = Regex.Match(stringLine3, @"Register: 0x0092 = 0x([0-9A-Z]+)");
System.Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1]);
// 0x0048
```

- `match.Groups[1]` Gets the string captured by group 1. Where as `match.Groups[0]` will have the entire match.

Comment: great response but sorry I should have been more specific, I am using C sharp, and this code doesn't work for it:(

Comment: great response, it makes complete sense but I am trying to do it using stringLine3 = Regex.Match(stringLine3,@"^Register: 0x0092 = 0x([0-9A-Z]+)").Value;  and it is giving me the whole string back

Comment: @JohnJ Yes, it is captured in group 1 use `Groups` to get it. Have updated the answer with code.